# expression is of wrong type error in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have created type for subj_code as below:

```
 TYPE t_c_subj_code IS TABLE OF student.subj_code%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

Field `i_Subj_Code` contains list of `subj_code`. I want to select `subj_code` which is not in `i_Subj_Code` list.
I am trying below procedure:

```
Procedure GET_Test(i_P_No in varchar2,
                    i_Subj_Code IN t_c_subj_code,
                    o_cursor out t_cursor) is 

BEGIN
    OPEN o_cursor FOR
         Select tt.c_subj_code 
         from student tt
    where 
        tt.i_P_No =i_P_No and
        tt.subj_code NOT IN
            (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(i_Subj_Code));
END;
```

Comment: Where have you declared this? This is an invalid declaration of a type outside PL/SQL, which means you've done it in the package specification/body?

Comment: Yes ,I have declared it in package specification. where we declare all functions and procedures name . Where i need to speciy it??

Comment: In SQL; `create or replace type <type_name> as object ...` you're using it in SQL, so you must declare it in SQL.

Comment: I am confused. I am recently started working on oracle. Well I have created type in package specification where i found preveiously created type.

Comment: @pallavi - but you're trying to use this new type in a different way to your oreviously created types. You can't use a PL/SQL type directly in a plain SQL statement; even if that statement is itself inside a Pl/SQL block.

Comment: ohh! so in PL/SQL where how i can do this??

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it in the one SQL statement you could implement a [pipelined function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm#CHDJEGHC) which returns the needed part of you collection and use it in the table function.